# Docker: "You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/"

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile which when I want to build results in the error

```
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Note that the image sets up a somewhat complex project with several dependencies that require quite a lot of space. For example, the list includes Qt. This is only a thing during the construction of the image, and in the end, I expect it to have a size of maybe 300 MB.

Now I found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578536/how-to-fix-e-you-dont-have-enough-free-space-in-var-cache-apt-archives

Given that, what I tried so far is:

- Freeing the space used by docker images so far by calling `docker system prune`
- Removing unneeded installation files by calling `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt autoclean`
- There was also the suggestion to remove data in `var/log`, which has currently a size of 3 GB. However, I am not the system administrator and thus wary to do such a thing.

Is there any other way to increase that space?
And, preferably, is there a more sustainable solution, allowing me to build several images without having to search for spots where I can clean up the system?

Comment: Try this suggestion. You might have a lot of unused images that need to be deleted.
https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx-starter/issues/5#issuecomment-276562225

Answer (score 31):

Converting a `@Dre` suggestion into the code, you might want to use Docker `prune` command for containers, images & volumes

```
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker volume prune
```

You can use these commands in sequence:

```
docker container prune; docker image prune; docker volume prune
```

Answer (score 22):

TLDR;

run

```sh
docker system prune -a --volumes
```

---

I tried to increase the disk space and prune the images, containers and volumes manually but was facing the issue again and again. When I tried to check the memory consumption on my machine, I found a lot of memory consumed by `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker` location. Did a system prune which cleaned up a lot of space and docker builds started working again.

Comment: Surprisingly, this is what worked for my case. I reclaimed only 1.5 GB space and there was enough space on the machine,  but I had hundreds of `cache objects`, whatever it means.

Comment: I went with a combination of your answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66926441/13402588). It will mean the next few builds I do will take forever since the cache is gone but it's probably a good idea to do this every few months. Kind of a 'spring cleaning'.

Comment: That was it, got 30GB back ... Surprisingly, I deleted everything visible in Docker Desktop, but obviously there was something more which was hidden.

Answer (score 18):

### Free Space without removing your latest images

Use the following command to see the different types of reclaimable storage (the `-v` verbose option provides more detail):

```
docker system df
docker system df -v
```

Clear the build cache (the `-a` option will remove unused build cache):

```
docker builder prune -a
```

Remove dangling images ( tagged images, old and previous image builds):

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

---

**Increase Disk image size using Docker UI**

Docker > Preferences > Resources > Advanced > adjust *Disk image size* > Apply & Restart

Comment: This answer makes it clear what is the reason and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, increasing the "Virtual Disk limit" in Docker Desktop's [Preference > Resources > Advanced] works for me.