# Error "no free space in /var/cache/apt/archives" in singularity container, but disk not full

Tags: python, ubuntu, singularity-container

I'm trying to reproduce results of an older research paper and need tp run a singularity container with nvidia CUDA 9.0 and torch 1.2.0.
Locally I have Ubuntu 20.04 as VM where I run `singularity build`. I follow the [guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal) to installing older CUDA versions.
This is the recipe file

```
#header
Bootstrap: docker
From: nvidia/cuda:9.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04

#Sections

%files
/home/timaie/rkn_tcml/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
/home/timaie/rkn_tcml/RKN/*

%post

# necessary dependencies
pip install numpy scipy scikit-learn biopython pandas

dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb

apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-9-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get update

export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-9.0"
export TORCH_EXTENSIONS_DIR="$PWD/tmp"
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD:$PYTHONPATH

%runscript
cd experiments
python train_scop.py --pooling max --embedding blosum62 --kmer-size 14 --alternating --sigma 0.4 --tfid 0
```

which runs fine and gets me an image.simg file. Then I try installing cuda through `sudo singularity exec image.simg apt-get install cuda` producing the following error

```
0 upgraded, 823 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 2661 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6822 MB of additional disk space will be used.
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

I read about a similar issue in docker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291124/docker-you-dont-have-enough-free-space-in-var-cache-apt-archives) but I don't know of something similar to `docker system prune` for Singularity.

I also tried freeing space through `apt autoremove` and `apt autoclean` without any success.

There should be enough space left on disk as running `df -H` gives

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2,1G     0  2,1G   0% /dev
tmpfs           412M  1,4M  411M   1% /run
/dev/sda5        54G   19G   33G  36% /
tmpfs           2,1G     0  2,1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,3M  4,1k  5,3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2,1G     0  2,1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      132k  132k     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop1       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop2      261M  261M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
/dev/loop3       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/core20/1405
/dev/loop4       69M   69M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop5       46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15177
/dev/loop6       57M   57M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop7       46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14978
/dev/sda1       536M  4,1k  536M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           412M   25k  412M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Does anyone know if the problem resides on my local Ubuntu, or with the nvidia docker image?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Why would you run `sudo singularity exec image.simg apt-get install cuda`? Why not add it to the `%post` section? As I understand it singularity needs `sudo` for building, but for `exec` you run it without `sudo` and there you just use your "private" files (the rest of the system is kinda frozen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [overview](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/build_a_container.html#overview) section of `singularity build` documentation

> build can produce containers in two different formats that can be specified as follows.
>
> - compressed **read-only** Singularity Image File (SIF) format suitable for production (default)
> - **writable** (ch)root directory called a sandbox for interactive development (`--sandbox` option)

Adding `--sandbox` should make the system files writable which should resolve your issue.

Ideally, I'd suggest adding any `apt-get install` commands to the `%post` section in your recipe file.

Comment: Solved my issue! Adding to `%post` section with `--sandbox`argument properly installed all packages. Thanks!